# How to change the real value of Complex array elements in c++

Tags: c++, complex-numbers

Hey I have a Complex double array and I want to change the values of it from another basic float array, so basically I want to copy all the float array values into the `real` value of each complex element.

I tried to iterate in a for loop and copy the value but I get errors such `lvalue required as left operand of assignment`

Here is my code:

```
typedef std::complex<double> Complex;

const Complex test[] = { 0.0, 0.114124, 0.370557, 0.0, -0.576201, -0.370557, 0.0, 0.0 }; // init the arr with random numbers

for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
    printf ( "  %4d  %12f\n", i, in[i] );
    test[i].real() = in[i]; // this line returns an error
}
```

can someone please let me know what the correct way of doing so as I'm new to this subject.

Comment: you're trying to assign the value of `in[i]` to the return value of a method, `test[i].real()` which doesn't make any sense. I'm not familiar with the complex type, but it probably has a member function to set the real part

Comment: yea It makes sense that it returns an error but I did it anyway to show what I'm trying to achieve. @koolmathsgames

Comment: Can you show us the definition of the `Complex` type? There's `std::complex<T>`, but that doesn't seem to be what you're using.

Comment: added @templatetypedef

Comment: I am trying to change the real value by coping each 'in' element value to 'test' real element value @KPCT

Comment: test[] was declared as const, and it cannot be modified. A vector<Complex> should be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

1. You cannot assign to the result of calling `std::complex::real()` - it returns a value, not a reference.  You need to use the `void real(T value);` overload instead, see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/real.
2. `test` is declared `const` so you cannot assign to it in any case

To fix these issues, change your code to this:

```
typedef std::complex<double> Complex;

Complex test[] = { 0.0, 0.114124, 0.370557, 0.0, -0.576201, -0.370557, 0.0, 0.0 };

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
    printf ( "  %4d  %12f\n", i, in[i] );
    test[i].real (in[i]);
}
```